# Is it possible to Improve this Jquery code?

Tags: jquery

I am currently doing this:

```
var currFilterList = "";
$('.prod-filters input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() { 
currFilterList += $(this).attr('data-groupid')+',';
});
```

I was thinking it could be cool to do something like:

```
var currFilterList = $(blahblah).each(function() { return += value; }
```

The other thing I wanted to do was to add an item to an array of JQUERY objects (which needed to be null initially, I tried merge, but doesn't work as its not an array of JQUERY objects, is there a way to do this?

```
var myArrayOfJqueryObjects = [];
foreach(blah) {
$('.myItem').ADDTO(myArrayOfJqueryObjects );
}
```

Thanks alot for any replies :)!!!

Comment: Your second question is unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write

```
var arr = $('.prod-filters input:checkbox:checked').map(function() { 
    return $(this).attr('data-groupid'); 
}).get();

var str = arr.join(',');
```

Comment: Thanks thats what I was looking for, have been looking for a solution like this for a long time so thanks again :)!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this would work, but worth a try:

```
var currFilterList = $('.prod-filters input[type=checkbox]:checked').map($(this).attr('data-groupid')).join(',');
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be considered improved...

```
var currFilterList = [];
$('.prod-filters input:checkbox:checked').each(function() { 
   currFilterList.push($(this).data('group-id'));
});

currFilterList = currFilterList.join(',');
```

Though the code will produce different output, I assumed you did not want a trailing `,`.